# Genitiv der literarischen Werke

Tags: grammatical-case, genitive

Wenn man den Genitiv eines literarischen Werks benutzen möchte, soll man z.B. "der Autor des *Zauberberg*s" oder "der Autor des *Zauberberg*" schreiben ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Der Duden "[richtiges und gutes Deutsch](https://books.google.de/books?id=1-HBDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA197&lpg=PA197&dq=flexion%20von%20buchtiteln&source=bl&ots=rut5n9ftwa&sig=Ba9yPFtP8mRtx_BT75YpSv0aUM8&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCiMGT8rHZAhUN3KQKHd_aD6cQ6AEILzAC#v=onepage&q=flexion%20von%20buchtiteln&f=false)" hat zu diesem Thema ein eigenes Kapitelchen unter "Buchtitel"

Ob man den Gesamttitel wörtlich zitieren oder Artikel und Possesivpronomen ändern und anpassen kann, hängt wohl ziemlich stark vom Bekanntheitsgrad des Werkes ab. Manche Buchtitel haben sich von Ihrer Eigenschaft als Titel schon gelöst und können als eigenständige Begrifflichkeiten stehen. So kann man ohne weiteres

> Als Thomas Mann seinen Zauberberg schrieb...

sagen (obwohl der Roman eigentlich korrekt "Der Zauberberg" heißt). Goethes Faust kann man daher auch als *den Faust* bezeichnen, obwohl der korrekte Titel wohl eher *Faust. Eine Tragödie* heißen müsste.

Bei einem eher unbekannten Werk sollte man das allerdings lassen, weil der Titel dann eben nicht mehr identifizierbar ist.

> Lieschen Müller hat ihren neuen Roman "Das Magische Tal" veröffentlicht.

Entscheidet man sich dafür, den Namen des Romans nicht wörtlich zu zitieren, sondern als neuen, eigenständigen Begriff zu verwenden (was bei *dem Faust* und *dem Zauberberg* wohl legitim ist), dann darf (und soll) man den Titel auch flektieren.

Entscheidet man sich dafür, den Buchtitel in Anführungszeichen zu setzen, und muss im Satzbau z.B. einen Artikel flektieren, wird der flektierte Artikel vor die Anführungszeichen gezogen:

> Thomas Mann, der Autor des "Zauberbergs",...

statt

> <s>Thomas Mann, der Autor "des Zauberbergs",...</s>

In seinen Beispielen sagt der Duden, dass auch der in Anführungszeichen stehende Titel flektiert werden muss. Ein extremeres Beispiel ist dabei

> ... sie las aus dem "Dreißigsten Jahr" von Ingeborg Bachmann vor.

Will man das nicht, weil man den Buchtitel nicht verändern möchte, sollte man Umschreibungen verwenden, wie

> ... sie las aus dem Buch "Das Dreißigste Jahr" von Ingeborg Bachmann vor.

Interessant ist noch, dass die Plural-/Singularform des Titels in der Regel auch die Verbform bestimmt:

> ... Schillers "[die] Räuber" waren ein Affront an die damalige Herrschaftsform

Answer (score 4):

Ich würde folgendes vorschlagen

> Der Autor des Romans "Der Zauberberg"

Man kann auch

> Der Autor des Zauberbergs

sagen, aber *des Zauberberg* ist inkonsequent weil es den Artikel der mit zum Titel gehört ändert, aber den Titel konstant hält. Also ändere es entweder komplett oder umschreibe es.